# How can I change my background on Google Meet with my iPad 9 (iPadOS 15.6.1)?

Tags: ipad, google, video-conference

I'd like to change my background on Google Meet with my iPad 9 (iPadOS 15.6.1). Typically I click on [image], but I don't see that button:

[image]

How can I change my background on Google Meet with my iPad 9 (iPadOS 15.6.1)?